# Locating and Printing HTML Hyperlink name

Tags: python, html

I want to be able to grab 'link to google' and print it from this:

```
<a href= "http://www.google.com">link to google</a>
```

This bottom code is able to grab the link, but I'm not sure how to make it grab the normal text.

```
def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):

          if tag == 'a':
               self.anchor = True
               if self.anchor == True:
                    for attr in attrs:
                         if attr[0] == 'href':
                              print(attr[1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it with `handle_data`:

```
def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    if tag == 'a':
        self.anchor = True

def handle_data(self, data):
    if self.anchor:
        print('anchor data is:', data)
    self.anchor = False
```

That will go into an `a` tag and set `self.anchor` true, then stumble upon data (within the tag) and if the last tag was `a` will print the data. Anyways, after that round, the `self.anchor` will be false again, preventing multiple false anchors detection.